# Using callIFrameFunction to send multiple args Flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, google-maps, iframe

I'm using IFrame to load an gmaps page in my Flex application. I need to pass latitude and longitude to my javascript function in the html loaded by the Frame. These are my functions.

Flex:

```
private function createMarker(event:MouseEvent):void{
var position : Array = [-25, 130];
IFrame.callIFrameFunction('putMarker', position);
}
```

JS:

```
document.putMarker= function(latitude,longitude){
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, longitude);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});
}
```

When i send just one of argument the function works fine, but when i try to send two or more arguments i fail.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your variable declaration: `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(longitude, longitude);` you've put longitude twice. Try changing that to `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitiude, longitude);` and let us know if it works!